# Retrieve and display value of radio options via jQuery

Tags: jquery, get, radio-button

I'm trying to have an alert box show the value of the radio option I have selected.
HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" /> Female
```

When I choose one of those and set up and alert box to show me what i choose (as a test), it doesn't work.
I know that other people are telling to set this up like:

```
var sex = $('input[name=sex]:checked').val();
```

However, when i put that, the entire script just craps on itself. Nothing works.
The script I have before looked like:

```
var sex = $('input[name=sex]:checked');
```

and with that the script still worked, but the alert only showed "[object Object]".
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the value of a radio button is on/off.  You might want to try using:

```
 var sex = $('input[name=sex]:checked').attr('value');
```

On the other hand, I don't see anything about your code that should cause it to fail (unless there's a bug in jQuery that can't handle your custom values).

Have you used Firefox/Firebug to see what the console error is?  It may be something completely unrelated.

Comment: I dont know how to use FireBug to find errors, only temporarily edit script.

Comment: Your code made it stop too. I have a form with radio's and when i hit submit it went to the action, the jQuery didn't disable it's default.

Comment: You need to post more code.  Also, if you want to prevent a form from submitting in a jQuery callback you need to prevent the default action , either explicitly or by returning false from the callback.